# if 2 commands with same filename exists in PATH variable, which will get executed?

Tags: shell, path

I have read that the shell searches the command in all the directories available in the PATH variable. My first question is what if 2 directories have the files for a command, which one will be executed ? 
 Second question is, does the shell searches in the directories shown in PATH variable recursively or not ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> what if 2 directories have the files for a command, which one will be
>   executed ?

The first one wins i.e. the first directory in the `PATH` where the desired file is found, is executed.

> does the shell searches in the directories shown in PATH variable
>   recursively or not ?

Non-recursively.

Comment: Can we decide the order of directories in PATH variable, and if yes , how  ?

Comment: @user3150716 `PATH` takes `:` separated directories to look at; just maintain the order you want while declaring the `PATH`.

Comment: @user3150716 You put the first one, then a colon, then the second one, then a colon then the third one. You might also find `type command` useful, it shows which command is used.